# JSF 2 valuechangeListener on checkbox works only for uncheck

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

```
<a4j:ajax render="tree">
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkEntry" value="#{bean.selected}" immediate="true"  disabled="false" valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeActive}"/>
  </a4j:ajax>
```

My checkbox for JSF is triggering the event "bean.changeActive", when I uncheck my checkbox..but when rechecking it, it doesn't trigger
The form tag is properly used..
any help on this regard is appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually not interested in the value change event. You are interested in the click event. The checkbox value remains the same. It's only the checked state which changes. It's the checked state which controls whether the value will be sent or not.

Use the `click` event instead and attach a `listener` on it.

```
<a4j:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.changeActive}" render="tree">
```